# Problems with XPath <!DOCTYPE> when parsing boost::serialization generated xml in VBS

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript

I have simplified xml config, generated by boost::serialization:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="5">
  <path>D:\test</path>
</boost_serialization>
```

I want to edit `path` node text using VBS, but while `<!DOCTYPE>` tag presented in xml file i cant get node with XPath request.

```vb
set xmlConf = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlConf.Async = "False"
xmlConf.Load("conf.xml")
'xmlConf.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", ""
set pathNode = xmlConf.selectSingleNode("/boost_serialization/path")
if not pathNode is nothing then
  WScript.Echo pathNode.Text
else
  WScript.Echo "NOTHING"
end if
```

Is there any hidden namespace that i should mention in commented line? Or there is some other trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript doesn't seem to recognize the DOCTYPE. Check the `ParseError` property of your XML object. This is what I get from your XML sample:

```
>>> Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
>>> xml.Async = False
>>> xml.Load "C:\Temp\test.xml"
>>> WScript.Echo Hex(xml.ParseError.ErrorCode)
C00CE00D
>>> WScript.Echo xml.ParseError.Reason
The element 'boost_serialization' is used but not declared in the DTD/Schema.
```

On a more general note: `Microsoft.XMLDOM` is outdated. Use `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0` instead.

---

After some more research: you may be able to work around the issue as described [here](http://www.svlada.com/blog/how-to-evaluate-xpath-when-doctype-present-in-xml-declaration/).

```vbs
Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xml.Async = False
xml.ValidateOnParse = False
xml.SetProperty "ProhibitDTD", False
xml.SetProperty "ResolveExternals", False

xml.Load "C:\path\to\conf.xml"

Set node = xml.SelectSingleNode("//path")
If node Is Nothing Then
  WScript.Echo "NOTHING"
Else
  WScript.Echo node.Text
End If
```